# Execute a function/method digited by the user

Tags: c#

I want to know, if in the .net have a class to call a function/method in run time...

e.g:

Enter with a method name to call: sum(10,20)

The code sample, of my Ideia is something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void sum(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a + b);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter with a method name to call: ");
        string a = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        // SAMPLE OF IDEA
        ProcessMacro PrM = new ProcessMacro(a);
    }
}
```

So, It's possible to do this ?
If yes, how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty easy to do with reflection. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial

Comment: Considering your sample of "sum", perhaps you plan on using a general math/scripting?  Perhaps FLEE can be useful if that's the case: http://flee.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand your question. You want something like a `eval` function.
String to Code ? As asawyer said, it is possible using reflection

Check out

[C# Eval Function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13335/C-Eval-Function)